# Self signed key certificate

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509, dsa

I'm trying to figure out how to create an X.509 certificate containing a self-signed DSA public key (SSK) in C#.

Having given up on the native C# crypto library which doesn't seem to allow this, I've been looking at the Bouncy Castle library.

However despite a description to the contrary, the download doesn't contain any docs.

I have been wading through the library classes but there are a lot!

I just need to generate a random key pair, sign them and save them in a certificate file.

Has anyone done this and are you able to point me to a good example, or even maybe supply an example?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We successfully did this a while back (but ended up needing to use "non self signed certificates")
We based our implementation on the following example from Doug E. Cook.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: That's a really good start, thanks! Any idea how to save it to a valid X509 cert file?

Comment: byte[] baCert = CreateSelfSignCertificatePfx( "CN=MYCERT", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(3650), "MyCertPW");
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\myCertFile.pfx", baCert);
(If working off the example in the previously referenced link)

Comment: That's exactly what I did! And your answer is correct. I just need to convert the pfx to a crt format, but that's another question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been generating self signed RSA certificates with Bouncy castle, this should let you start your own experiments:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/how-to-create-x509certificate2.html

Comment: That looks good, but the code sample uses a class called RsaKeyPairGenerator; do you know how to reference this? Or even better, a DSA version? Thanks

Comment: There is the DSAKeyPairGenerator, you couldn't have missed it.

Comment: It needed `using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;` which wasn't mentioned.